# Codeigniter - How to get Other user session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using chat in codeigniter here I'm tring to get active users so that I can display in the chat whether the user is online or offline.
I tried the following but the result was empty.

```
$this->session->all_userdata();
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using database sessions, potentially you could verify the login status using a call to the ci_sessions table (or whatever you have named it). You can then use a simple query to validate if they have been browsing within the last hour (or whatever) and validate them as being online.

Sample SQL query for this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) AS 'timestamp' from ci_sessions
WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 HOUR))
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This would return all the users active in the last hour (the timestamp col is updated each time a page is requested)

You can also grab the users details out of the 'data' column...

```
$this->session->all_userdata()
```

will not return all logged in users only all available data of the current logged in user

Comment: Like this implementation using session data

Answer (score 0):

You need to use extra field in table as "fld_userlogin". And manage with this field if user login fld_userlogin will be 1. other wise 0. after logout fld_userlogin will be 0. It's very easy compare session. all the best

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use web sockets as I assume you want instant feedback if a user is online or offline. Check out Ratchet (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world), I'm sure there are CI implementations that use this or something similar. Really depends on the scope of your chat app and how instant you want feedback.